# Не получается добавить фон справа при ховере строки таблицы выбивающийся за ее край

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, bootstrap-table

Приветствую всех! У меня есть табличка, хочу с помощью стилей сделать так, чтобы при наведении на каждую из строк фон ховера распространялся за таблицу влево и вправо на `20px` в пределах контейнера. Как это можно сделать?
Добавил в [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/t2vgf5pb/6/)

```css
.table-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.table-products {
background-color:#d1edff;
}
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover {
  background-color: #006cd0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="table table-products">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Фото</th>
          <th>Код</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>В наличии</th>
          <th>Руб. без НДС</th>
          <th>Руб. с НДС</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсветка продолжается ровно и не затрагивает границы.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}

.table-products {
  background-color: #d1edff;
}

.table-products > tbody > tr > td,
.table-products > tbody > tr > th {
  padding: .25em;
}


.table-products > tbody > tr:hover td:first-child,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover th:first-child,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover td:last-child,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover th:last-child {
  position: relative;
}

.table-products > tbody > tr:hover,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > th:first-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before {
  background-color: #006cd0;
}

.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > th:first-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > th:first-child:before {
  right: 100%;
}

.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before,
.table-products > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child:before {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="table table-products">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Фото</th>
          <th>Код</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>В наличии</th>
          <th>Руб. без НДС</th>
          <th>Руб. с НДС</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>100201</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><a>текст</a>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>125</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>15500</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если без `JS`, то можно через `position: absolute;` для блока (например псевдо элемента `:after`), но будет проблема с динамической высотой ячейки таблицы, поэтому лучше задать фикс высоту.

В примере нету предотвращения увеличения высоты ячейки таблицы при длинном тексте!

Так же [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/fk5gqqk4/2/)

### UPD

Добавил очищение фона ячеек и обновил [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/ja00gbb9/2/)

Проблему я высотой строки на `CSS` никак не решить (по крайней мере мне не известно решение).

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.table-wrapper {
    padding:20px;
}
.table-products td {
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 70px;
}
.table-products tr {
    background: #fff;
}
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover td,
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover {
    background: none !important;
}
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color:#006cd0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table class="table table-products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Фото</th>
      <th>Код</th>
      <th>Название</th>
      <th>В наличии</th>
      <th>Руб. без НДС</th>
      <th>Руб. с НДС</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></td>
      <td><p>100201</p></td>
      <td><p><a>текст</a></p></td>
      <td><p>125</p>
      </td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></td>
      <td><p>100201</p></td>
      <td><p><a>текст</a></p></td>
      <td><p>125</p>
      </td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></td>
      <td><p>100201</p></td>
      <td><p><a>текст</a></p></td>
      <td><p>125</p>
      </td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
      <td><p>15500</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: да, нужно предусмотреть длину текста
http://jsfiddle.net/fk5gqqk4/3/

Comment: к тому же, если фон не белый, то не работает..

Comment: @Вася, я же об этом написал. Для белой заливки таблицы можно для всевдоблока `:after` указать `z-index` большой и заливку сделать с непрозрачностью

Comment: тут вам только `JS` поможет

Comment: Или еще проще, отключать заливку ячеек – http://jsfiddle.net/ja00gbb9/2/

Answer (score 1):

может так

```css
.table-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
}
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color:#006cd0;
}
.table-products>thead>tr th:nth-child(8n + 1), 
.table-products>thead>tr th:nth-child(8n + 8), 
.table-products>tbody>tr td:nth-child(8n + 1), 
.table-products>tbody>tr td:nth-child(8n + 8) {
    background-color:#fff;
    border: none;
}
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover td:nth-child(8n + 1), 
.table-products>tbody>tr:hover td:nth-child(8n + 8) {
    background-color:#006cd0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="table table-products">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Фото</th>
                    <th>Код</th>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>В наличии</th>
                    <th>Руб. без НДС</th>
                    <th>Руб. с НДС</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>100201</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><a>текст</a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>125</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>100201</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><a>текст</a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>125</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>100201</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><a>текст</a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>125</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>15500</p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению нет.. `table` ужался, а этого не должно быть.. - он должен занимать всю ширину контейнера. я пытался сделать с помощью псевдоклассов `:before` и `:after`, но пока не получается..

Comment: больше никаких мыслей нету?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/eohk98oy/

Comment: все, разобрался! надо было 6 столбцов оставить)

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить пустые столбцы слева и справа таблицы и указать нужную им ширину, а у родительского `.table-wrapper` убрать `padding`.

Например http://jsfiddle.net/ngp67hwd/

Comment: и где здесь по вашему фон выходит за пределы таблицы при наведении? это совсем не то, что нужно